# ¿Qué palabra se puede usar para expresar repetición basada en "días", que no sea "diario"?

Tags: vocabulario, solicitud-de-término, adjetivos, tiempo

"Diario" (fuera del documento escrito) tiene exclusivamente el uso adverbial de "todos los días": *me como un plato de arroz diario*. Pero lo que quiero consultar es la idea de "día" pero con otra palabra, por la misma línea que hay entre "año" y "anual".

Quiero expresar la siguiente idea: un evento que ocurre dos días cada semana. Hipoteticé las expresiones "evento **bijornada** cada semana", o "evento **bidiario** cada semana". ¿Qué se les ocurre a los miembros del sitio?

Comment: ¿por qué piensas que diario no se puede usar como adjetivo?  Así lo recoge el DLE.  Si algo ocurre dos veces por semana, es *bisemanal*.  Si algo ocurre dos veces por día o cada dos días, se  podría llamarlo *bidiario* sin problema.  También tenemos *diurnal* pero es refiere al día (frente a la noche)

Comment: @guifa ¿de dónde sacaste esa información del uso de diario, podrías compartir el enlace por favor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Además de "diario" también está:

> [**dial**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DeJwdh0%7CDeMWi7d%7CDeOsnAz)
>
> Del lat. diālis 'de un día'.
>
> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a un día.

A partir del cual puedes formar "bidial", "tridial", etc.

Y como curiosidad, en el diccionario no están "duano" ni "biduano", pero sí están:

> [**triduano, na**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=adEKsUk)
>
> Del lat. triduānus.
>
> 1. adj. De tres días.
>
> [**cuatriduano, na**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BUZWXpW)
>
> Del lat. quatriduānus, de quatridium 'espacio de cuatro días'.
>
> 1. adj. De cuatro días.

---

(Después de responder me di cuenta de que no era lo que buscabas. La [respuesta de ukemi](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26298/13628) va por mejor camino, pero dejemos esta como complemento.)

Comment: Por interés: `dial, diario, cuotidiano, cotidiano, circadiano | ... | triduano | cuatriduano | bisemanal | ... | semanal, hebdomadario | ... | trimensual | ... | duodenario |  ... | quincenal, bimensual | ... | mensual | bimestral | trimestral | cuatrimestral | ... | semestral, bianual | ... | anual, cadañero | bienal | ... | cuatrienal, cuadrienal | ... | decenal | ... | quindenial | ... | vicenal, *veinteñal | tricenal  | cuadricenal | ... | diuturno | ... | eterno, eternal, sempiterno, eviterno` y *centenario, milenario* etc

Comment: Algunos de esos términos tienen definiciones muy específicas en contexto científico. Tuve un encuentro cercano de ese tipo con el circadiano. La definición va más allá de los procesos psicológicos de sueño  y hambre a ciertas horas del día. En particular tiene que ver con procesos celulares a nivel molecular  y maravillosos mecanismos hechos de grasa y proteínas que funcionan como relojes. Lo chistoso es que todas las creaturas de este planeta comparten el mismo mecanismo. Hasta especies primitivas de medusas se "echan un coyotito" de vez en cuando. (Coyotito=siesta)

Comment: Al menos en España, 'dial' refiere únicamentea la radio. En este contexto es probable que no te entiendan.

Answer (score 7):

«Dos días cada semana» no quiere decir «dos veces por *día*», sino «dos veces por *semana*».

Por lo tanto, la palabra que buscas es [*bisemanal*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5bjsZzf):

> ### [bisemanal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5bjsZzf)
>
> `De bi- y semana.`
>
> 1. `adj.` Que se hace u ocurre dos veces por semana.

el hipotético **bidiario* significaría:

- "algo que ocurre dos veces por día", o
- "algo que ocurre cada dos días" (como *semanal* también puede significar *quincenal*)

Comment: *Bisemanal* puede ser también cada dos semanas, por lo que "dos veces por semana" es más preciso y más usual.

Answer (score 2):

Otra alternativa para evitar ambigüedades o el uso de prefijos o sufijos de escaso uso que pudiesen generar duda o confusión, es usar múltipos de horas para indicar el periodo.

De hecho, esta es la razón por la que la periodicidad en la dosificación de medicamentos se expresa en múltipos de horas: nunca te quedará la duda de si el evento debe ocurrir cada dos semanas o cada dos veces a la semana, como en el caso de *bisemanal*.

Indicar ***cada 48 horas*** es un periodo de dos días sin ambigüedades. ***Cada 72 horas*** es un periodo de 3 días sin ambigüedad.

Para periodos más largos en los que el número de horas no es computable de inmediato en una operación mental (mayores a 72 horas), podemos extender la técnica a usar múltiplos de días.
Así, ***cada tercer día*** equivale a cada 72 horas y ***cada siete días*** asegura un evento semanal.